# Time series: ets() Box Cox transformation and AICc comparation

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, aic

I am using `ets()` from the R `forecast` package and AICc criterion to select the best model.

Suppose we have a time series denoted by `y`:

```
x <- BoxCox(y, BoxCox.lambda(y))
fit <- ets(y)
fit2 <- ets(x, lambda=BoxCox.lambda(y))
```

Is AICc from `fit2` comparable with AICc fit? In other words, Does `ets()` make some internal transformation that provides a comparabe AICc?

Comment: I am bit confused on what is going on here. According to ets() function definition if lambda value is provided, the data is transformed before model is estimated, which means the code should have been fit <- ets(y) fit2 <- ets(y, lambda=BoxCox.lambda(y)) # changed from x to y I think the above code is doing double BoxCox transformation. But I am not sure if you can compare AIC values.

Answer (score 3):

No, they are not comparable. Because you are fitting your `ets` to two different data sets, one with and the other one without BoxCox transformation. By default, when you don't provide the argument of lambda, it is considered as NULL and will be ignored. You cannot compare the AIC ( or AICc) values, whenever you change your data set. A very good reference here is [Model Selection and Multimodel Inference Second Edition](http://www.mun.ca/biology/quant/ModelSelectionMultimodelInference.pdf).